# Retrieve extended styles

Tags: styled-components

My code is:

```
styled(Button)`
  color: ${(props: any) => COLOR_I_CHOOSE}
`
```

I was following the "extending styles" section in the docs - https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#extending-styles

`Button` is  a custom styled component. I want to pass in a color so it overrides the internal setting of the color to `COLOR_I_CHOOSE`. I have control over the internals. In the internals I am trying to detect if any styled overrides were provided and use that.

Internally I set the CSS like this:

const primaryChildre

```
nCSS = css`
  color: ${(props: any) => {
    console.log('props:', props);
    // TODO: test if props has override on color and use that
    // PSEUDOCODE: if (props.styleExtensions.color) return props.styleExtensions.color
    return props.inverse
      ? props.theme.ns().colors.brand
      : props.theme.ns().colors.white;
  }};
`;
```

I logged out `props` here, but can't figure out how to get that. I want to do as the pseudocode comment in the above.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button> Hello</Button> // default color
```

The following will override the default color of `Button` if the passed color is not red.

```
const MyRedTextButton = styled(Button)`
  color:  ${(props: any) => props.color === 'red' ? 'inherit' : props.color}
`
```

Then:

```
<MyRedTextButton color="red"> Hello </MyRedTextButton> // color of 'Hello' = the color of <Button/>

<MyRedTextButton color="blue"> Hello </MyRedTextButton> // color of 'Hello' = blue
```

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Do I really have to provide a custom prop of `customColor` though? Shouldn't restyling the button send those styles down?

Comment: You can hardcode the color that you want to use or pass it as prop in  my code. I do not fully understand your question - what do you mean by "sending those styles down?" down to where?

Comment: What is your expected output from `primaryChildrenCSS`?

Comment: I expect that if `styled(Button)'color:red'` then `primaryChildrenCSS` should give color `red`

Comment: No, styled components does not work like that. Only possible if  `primaryChildrenCSS = styled(MyButton)` - after having overriden the styles already in my answer

Comment: I was thinking the docs was ssaying this was possible - https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#extending-styles (the extending styles section)

Comment: My updated code in the answer does just  - it overrides the `color` property of `Button`.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, but in your custom styled component of `Button` can you test if there is an override, and log out that override? For example sake, within the component `Button`, can you catch if the override color is "red" and then turn this override into green?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199908/discussion-between-matthew-barbara-and-noitidart).